# Find directories within directories ending in 'l0' that do not contain '*18*' in their names

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I am currently doing `find . ! -name '*18*' -name '*l0*' -type d` but it is listing all the parent directories like 'd1_l0' , 'd2_l0', 'd3_l0' etc only. I actually want subdirectories like 'd1_l0/[15*,16*,17*]', 'd2_l0/[15*,16*,17*]', 'd3_l0/[15*,16*,17*]'

Comment: -name only matches the last part of the path .... if you want to match the entire path you need to use `-path`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the leaves with find you can use `-links`:

```
$ find -type d -path '*l0*' ! -path '*18*' -links 2
```

<sup>Directories with no subdirectories contains two hardlinks one to itself and one to its parent `. ..`</sup>